# Player 2 is not registered in Tekken 7 in arcade mode

Tags: tekken-7

I am playing Tekken 7 in arcade mode, not story mode, in arcade mode, we can start with 1st player vs cpu and keep progressing to next stage and player 2 can challenge player 1 with controller, anytime.
But it seems player 2 and player 1 controller register same and control only 1st player.
In options-controller option menu there is setting for player 1 only, player 2 settings seems unavailable.
In vs mode, however, controller 2 actually controls player 2.
But it doesn't work in arcade mode.

According to [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/tekken-7/Arcade_Mode) it should be easy:

> During Arcade mode, you can have another player push start and begin a two player battle at any time. This is the same like past Arcade modes that worked the exact same way. Once a battle between two players is complete, the winner of the bout will continue playing through the Arcade Mode matches like normal.

I don't understand how to fix this problem.